# Connect Ubuntu core to OpenVPN Server

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to connect Ubuntu Core 18 to my OpenVPN network.
Installing the `snap classic` package and `sudo apt install openvpn`, it doesn't works, I can't start `openvpn` service.

With `easy-openvpn-server` [1](https://snapcraft.io/easy-openvpn-server) I can install only a Server, but not a client.

With `easy-openvpn` [2](https://snapcraft.io/easy-openvpn), I can't import the .ovpn profile because of a generic error.

Any idea? Can you help me?

Thanks, Roberto

Comment: What's the "generic error"?

Comment: `Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: profile.ovpn`. The file exists and works in other classic ubuntu environment.